# Symfony - how switch and work with locale

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

what is the best practise how to work with locale in the twig templates:

- how switch between languages (with language switcher in template) and how to keep an existing URL with just a change of language
- how create URL with locale support

For example:
I have 2 languages (**ES** and **EN**), default language is ES, for my home page I create 2 Route Anotations for  `/` (for default language, in this case ES) and for `/{_locale}/` (for other languages) in my Controller file.

And now I need to get locale parameter to my twig template to my URL, but only if I will not on my default language.

Manually rewrite URL works fine, but is there any easy way how add locale parameter to URL when I creating on my twig templates ?

The actual value of the variable locale can be passed to Controller, but is there any better way to got it in twig?

**EDIT:**

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/{_locale}/branches", name="branches",
 *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
 *     )
 * 
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    return $this->render('branches/index.html.twig');
}
```

index.html.twig

```
<li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'branches' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{ path('branches') }}" class="">{{ 'header.menu.branches'|trans }}</a>
                </li>
```

I got

No route found for "GET /branches" i use this URL http://localhost:8080/en/branches (works OK) and http://localhost:8080/branches (ERROR) I must use something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/branches/", name="branches_def",
 *     defaults={"_locale":"%locale%"},
 *     )
 * @Route(
 *     "/{_locale}/branches/", name="branches",
 *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
 *     )
 * 
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    return $this->render('branches/index.html.twig');
}
```

URL generating with path is OK, but if I delete locale parameter from my URL in my browser I got this error.

Thanks a lot for any usefull advice

Comment: Try this bundle https://packagist.org/packages/jms/i18n-routing-bundle

Comment: According to your edit, better is to use two separated actions with own annotations parameters

Comment: Like in my example UPPER ? Better way is use 2 @Route Annotions ? One for locale and second for URL without this param ?

Comment: Two separated actions will help to debug and to find cause of potential bug, if you know that logic in actions will be complicated in future. But if not, you also can use as 2 @Route annotations, it is fully working, just checked it on test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. uncomment row `translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }` in config.yml
2. declare needed variables in the same file:

   ```
   parameters:
       locale: en
       app.locales: en|lv|ru
   ```
3. declare your needed route in routing.yml like this:

   ```
   contact_us:
       path: /{_locale}/contact
       defaults:
           _controller: 'AppBundle:Default:contact'
           _locale: '%app.locales%'
   ```
4. use `{{ path('another_route') }}` without parameters, in case `another_route` declared with _locale placeholder. Also for single text translation use `{{ 'home.title'|trans }}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post, `{{ path('another_route') }}` gives me in twig template actual `_locale` parameter to my URL ? For example if I have actualy `/en/` path in home and I need to go `/en/contact/`, then `en` parameter was add automaticaly to my URL ? I use 2 routes anotation for one page 1. for default lang  (`/` for home, `/conatcts/` etc) and 2. for others languages (`/en/` for home, `/en/conatcts/`, `/de/contacts/` etc)

Comment: Yes, in your example `en` parameter will be added automatically

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I use this `/**
     * @Route(
     *     "/{_locale}/branches", name="braches",
     *     requirements={"_locale":"%app_locales%"}
     *     )
     * 
     */` and It works fine for  `/en/branches`, but when I use `/branches` in url without locale I got error message then route `/branches` **does not exist**, in this case I must have 2 routes for each Action in my Controller ?

Comment: in url you should use route name (contact_us), instead of route path (/{_locale}/contact}). And after that you shouldn't use the second route

Comment: Only part which I missing (from your example) In my controller route annotation is this `_controller: 'AppBundle:Default:contact'`, but when I delete from URL /en/branch -> /branch I got error message **route does not exist**, URL generating in twig works fine now

Comment: So your link looks exactly `<a href="{{ path('branches') }}">link</a>` and you still have error? I took route name `branches` from your route name annotation above

Answer (score 1):

save your locale into a cookie and then inside your twig file create links like `<a href="{{ path('your-path-name', {'locale': app.request.cookies.get('LOCALE_COOKIE')}) }}">`

I am not sure if you will get an error or a null value (which will help you with your default locale in your controller route) if the cookie is not set but you should try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but It is possible use this with session too ? In the best Way I am looking for some easy way how can I do this. This entry of a variable is, in my opinion, too long to use for every URL address and difficult. I am using my own translations files in `app/`, and one of the way is add locale parameter in each controller as parameter to the twig template, but it is possible do this automaticaly or in base Controller ?